# jquery-ui-timepicker-addon not working in codeigniter 2.1

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm using jquery-ui-timepicker-addon not working in codeigniter 2.1.4, in which the followings are called to display the date/time picker.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
```

But it is not showing the datetime picker controller in my view.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your view? Also, check your script's src. CodeIgniter and the timepicker don't have any relation to each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
you missed css file 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm,dd,yy'});
});
</script>

<input type="text" name="date" id="date"/>
```

Comment: Thanks...But my requirement is to have both together date/time.   $('#inputDate').datetimepicker({
   controlType: 'select',
 timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt z',
 timezone: 'MT',
 stepMinute: 15,
   beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
            var offset = $(input).offset();
            var height = $(input).height();
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                inst.dpDiv.css({ top: (offset.top + height + 4) + 'px', left: offset.left + 'px' })
            }, 1);
         }
  

});

Comment: Thanks...i have fixed it.